# If piping two subshells that each overwrite a file, why is the file's contents unpredictable?

Tags: bash

I would like to learn why, after entering the following command, "(echo "1" > file) | (echo "2" > file)", in bash, the content of the file named "file" can be the number 2 - sometimes.  Usually, the content of file is 1 after running the command, but sometimes it is 2.

```
[root@server root]# (echo "1" > file) | (echo "2" > file)
[root@server root]# cat file
2
```

[From PuTTY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJu7t.png)

Comment: Both sides of a pipeline *run at the same time*. If you're running both of these subshells at the same time, why do you *expect* there to be any predictability to their output?

Comment: There isn't even any guarantee that the file will have *one* line as its final contents. Both subshells could truncate `file` before either shell writes any of its output, resulting in either `1\n2\n` or `2\n1\n` as the final contents of the file.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  What makes you think I would expect the output to be predictable if the two subshells are running at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the pipeline elements execute in parallel and because the `echo` on the right doesn't wait for any trigger; it doesn't wait for input before executing its output action.

If we make it this:

```
( echo "1" > file ) | ( read; echo "2" > file)
```

then we consitently get `2` in the file. The second pipeline element has a `read` which blocks until it receives input, or an end of input indication. Thus the pipeline element is suspended in `read` until the left `echo` exits. Then it executes the `echo "2" > file` which predictably overwrites the `1`. By that time, the left `echo` is no longer running, so the race is resolved.

By the way, we don't need the subshelling parentheses in the original version. It is equivalent to:

```
echo "1" > file | echo "2" > file
```

and my modified version can be:

```
echo "1" > file | ( read; echo "2" > file)
```

Comment: Why to use `read`? To consitently get 2 just use chained commands: `echo "1" > file && echo "2" > file` or ';' instead of '&&'

Comment: @oklas That's no longer a small change which demonstrates how to get the behavior from the elements that are still placed in the original pipeline. I'm assuming that the OP already knows that statements in a script separated by a semicolon execute sequentially.

Answer (score 3):

Your snippet create two separated process running in parallel. Operation system do not guarantee which will started or finished first. Both of your process write output in same file. Therefore which one is finshed last that output will present in output file.

Answer (score 1):

A race condition is expected to produce inconsistent results, and a race condition is what you are producing.

The first comand line has two subshells changing the same file at the same time - depending on which subshell writes out last, the contents of the file will be what this subshell wrote.